# On equivalence between limsup and supremum of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding properties of $\limsup$.

Take a sequence ${\{S_n\}}$. Define $E$ as a set of all subsequential limits of ${\{S_n\}}$. I am trying to show that

$\sup E = \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sup\limits_{k>N}S_k$

My approach is if there is real number $p = \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sup\limits_{k>N}S_k$. I need to show that

$\forall\varepsilon>0.\exists x\in E$ such that $x\in B_\varepsilon(p)$, where $B_\varepsilon(p)$ denotes ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around p.

And thats where I am stuck. Are there any other approaches? Any clue/hint will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first your attempt will not work because if $E\subset \{S_n\}$, and we know $$p:=\limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n$$

You're attempt might work but I think its quite hard because the set $E$ contains all limits of series $\{e_n\}\subset \{S_n\}$. Which is a lot and there some really strange ones in there.

Just assume that this is not true so:

$$\sup E > \limsup S_n \quad \quad\lor\quad \quad \sup E < \limsup S_n$$

I guess you will find it to prove really easy that this can't happen as then there is a subseries $e_n$ where:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e_n > \limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n $$